# How to subtract micros()?

Tags: arduino-uno, time, mathematics

I am attempting to calculate the time between pulses by comparing the micros() timestamp. I understand that you cannot just simply subtract unsigned longs, but I cannot understand what the alternative for it is.

Below is a simplified version of code. On pin 6 I receive 2ms long pulses every 2ms comparing the times returns "-19728". I'm planning to make the pulses much shorter once I figure out this math problem.

Site note: I'm using pulses to make two Arduinos send simple data via digital pins.

Thanks you.

```
int pinReceiver = 6;
int val = 0;
int isReceiving = 0;
int pauseLength = 0;
unsigned long timeStart = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinReceiver,INPUT);  
}

void loop() {
  noInterrupts();
  val = digitalRead(pinReceiver);

  if(val==HIGH){
    if(isReceiving==0){ //Pulse begins
      isReceiving = 1;
      pauseLength = micros() - timeStart;
      Serial.println(pauseLength);
    }

  } else {
    if(isReceiving==1){ //Pulse ends
      isReceiving = 0;
      timeStart = micros();
    }
  }
  interrupts();
}
```

Comment: The calculation seems correct. Please try to also use `unsigned long` for `pauseLength`. That might be your problem

Comment: That definitely solved the problem. I assumed that since the difference would be such a short number it could be int. Thank you. I don't know how to mark this as solving answer.

Comment: I think its more about that you mixed unsigned and signed types. Tomorrow I will write an answer, that you can accept

Comment: what happens if you cast long to int ? ... pauseLength = (int)(micros() - timeStart);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long to Integer conversion will overflow the value and you'll get values in negative numbers.

Define the `pauseLength` as `unsigned long` to make it work.